# Mistakes when extracting date from datetime using as.Date function

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime

I need to get date from datetime, I used as.Date function

2016-11-04 15:12:00 --- 2016-11-04  -- true

2018-03-17 19:18:00 --- 2018-03-18  -- false, it should be 2018-03-17

I noticed when the time is greater than "17:00", the date is added 1 day. What is the reason? Is there a better way to get correct date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the datetime are stored in your local timezone whereas `as.Date` uses UTC timezone by default therefore you see change in dates extracted.

You need to bring both of them in the same timezone. For example, specify `tz` value as `Sys.timezone()` in `as.Date` and you'll get the same date as shown in your data.

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$datetime), tz = Sys.timezone())
```

Answer (score 2):

R datetimes are stored as UCT times. You then see them, i.e. `print` them, with an offset determined by your system timezone. You appear to be 24-17 = 7 timezones away from Greenwich (or Paris) at least at the moment. (When it's 17:00 in your timezone, it's midnight in Paris.) That might change by one unit after DST reverts to ordinary time. (That's another frequent cause of time confusion in R.)

It's 6:30 PM in the Pacific tz:

```
 tseq <- seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time()+24*60*60 , by="hour")
 table(as.Date(tseq))
#-------------------------
2021-07-18 2021-07-19 
        23          2
```